# How to initialize a UInt8MultiArray message

Tags: ros, std-msgs, multiarray, array, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not too much info on these (or any of the variants) on the wiki: what is the proper way to initialize these? I've tried:

```
const unsigned int data_sz = 10;
std_msgs::UInt8MultiArray m;

m.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());
m.layout.dim[0].size = data_sz;
m.layout.dim[0].stride = 1;
m.layout.dim[0].label = "bla";

// only needed if you don't want to use push_back
m.data.resize(data_sz);
```

for an array with 10, 1 byte elements, but I keep getting segfaults at the subscriber callback when accessing the `data` member (FIXED: see edit).

I couldn't find any examples anywhere, apart from http://alexsleat.co.uk/tag/multiarray/, but those snippets do not initialize any dimensions.

Is it programmers responsibility to keep the dimension objects in sync with the actual size of the `data` member, or is ROS doing some magic behind the scenes at serialization?

---

edit: as @Lorenz commented: `reserve` -> `resize`. I've left the bit about the segfaults in the question, even though that was fixed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37185/how-to-initialize-a-uint8multiarray-message/) by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-25**:
reserve might not do what you expect. It just causes the vector to allocate more memory but doesn't change its size, i.e. a call to vector's size method will still return 0. Instead, use the method resize.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-06-25**:
yes, just GDBed myself to that conclusion as well. Should've read the docs more carefully. Thanks for your reply. Point about  the documentation on the whole `MultiArray` thing being really thin / non existent stands though (imho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The snippet in my original post is basically how you initialize `MultiArrays`. Just `push_back()` a new `std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension` for each dimension and set it up according to the docs @Lorenz referenced.

Using `resize(n, std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension())` should also work.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-15**:
could you please extend on it via the `push_back()` approach?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the definition of the messages. The file `UInt8MultiArray` contains a comment:

```
# Please look at the MultiArrayLayout message definition for
# documentation on all multiarrays.
```

The file MultiArrayLayout.msg contains the following:

```
# The multiarray declares a generic multi-dimensional array of a
# particular data type.  Dimensions are ordered from outer most
# to inner most.

MultiArrayDimension[] dim # Array of dimension properties
uint32 data_offset        # padding bytes at front of data

# Accessors should ALWAYS be written in terms of dimension stride
# and specified outer-most dimension first.
# 
# multiarray(i,j,k) = data[data_offset + dim_stride[1]*i + dim_stride[2]*j + k]
#
# A standard, 3-channel 640x480 image with interleaved color channels
# would be specified as:
#
# dim[0].label  = "height"
# dim[0].size   = 480
# dim[0].stride = 3*640*480 = 921600  (note dim[0] stride is just size of image)
# dim[1].label  = "width"
# dim[1].size   = 640
# dim[1].stride = 3*640 = 1920
# dim[2].label  = "channel"
# dim[2].size   = 3
# dim[2].stride = 3
#
# multiarray(i,j,k) refers to the ith row, jth column, and kth channel.
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-06-25**:
Thanks. I've actually read those comments in the msg def. I guess my question was more 'why are there so few (none) actual (C++) examples for this?' than 'what is the meaning of all these fields?'. Simultaneously programming in 3+ languages also doesn't help.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-25**:
I guess people just don't use this kind of really generic messages. It's always better to define a message with meaningful slot names instead of using generic message types for everything.

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-15**:
Could someone extend on how to create multiple arrays I dont get the dim[i]-stuff and where to put it ? Also why push an multiarray into the same multiarray, `m.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy, following a working code tried on an Arduino Mega and ROS Kinetic:
Commands in ROS:

```
$ roscore
```

//New terminal

```
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=115200
```

//New terminal

```
$ rostopic echo /arr
```

Arduino Code for Publishing an array with 4 words:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

std_msgs::UInt16MultiArray arr;
ros::Publisher pub_arr( "/arr", &arr);

void setup() {
  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
  nh.initNode();
  arr.layout.dim = (std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension *)
  malloc(sizeof(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension)*2);
  arr.layout.dim[0].label = "height";
  arr.layout.dim[0].size = 4;
  arr.layout.dim[0].stride = 1;
  arr.layout.data_offset = 0;
  arr.data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*8);
  arr.data_length = 4;
  nh.advertise(pub_arr);

}

void loop() {    
  arr.data[0] = 1;
  arr.data[1] = 2;
  arr.data[2] = 3;
  arr.data[3] = 4; 
  pub_arr.publish(&arr);
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) with karma: 92 on 2017-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3